# Pulling out additional AD information in a SharePoint Designer workflow

Tags: sharepoint-designer, active-directory-import

In our organization we have an employee number and that number would be stored in a field in the Active Directory.

I'd like to be able to have someone fill out a form, without having to do any data entry for the employee number.

Is there a way I can create a workflow to populate a single line of text field from the active directory information as long as I know the name of the field?